# How to create a Factory-Boy factory for a model with TaggableManager field

Tags: django, django-taggit, factory-boy

How can I create a field in Factory-Boy to TaggableManager from django-taggit?

The following does not work:

First:

```py
class ExperimentFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Experiment
        django_get_or_create = ('owner', 'name', 'start_date', 'stop_date', )

    owner = factory.SubFactory(UserFactory)
    name = factory.Sequence(lambda n : 'Experiment %s' % n)

    start_date = fuzzy.FuzzyDate(start_date=datetime.date(2003, 2, 1), 
                                     end_date = datetime.date.today() + timedelta(days=4*52*7+5))

    tags = [u'abc, cde', u'xzy']
```

The error is: TypeError: 'tags' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Second: (with `factory.post_generation`). So Instead of the last line there is

```py
@factory.post_generation
def post_tags(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
    self.tags = [u'abc, cde', u'xzy']
    # self.save() # This does not have any effects
```

I get as result by `Experiment.objects.get(pk=1).tags` is []

For some details:

The testing of the objects in a `TestCase` is:

```py
experiment = ExperimentFactory(owner = self.user)
saved_experiment = Experiment.objects.get(name=experiment.name) 

self.assertEquals(len(experiment.tags), len(saved_experiment.tags.all())) # AssertError: 2 != 0
self.assertItemsEqual(experiment.tags, saved_experiment.tags.all())
```

The odd thing is that in `self.experiments` the tags are set. The `post_tags()` method is called.

The model is:

```py
class Experiment(models.Model):
     owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='experiments') 

     name = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='')
     start_date = models.DateField()

     tags = TaggableManager()
```

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else coming here who wants a more generalised example of using Factory Boy and django-taggit, the Factory Boy docs [include a Many-to-Many example](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html#simple-many-to-many-relationship) which is useful. So:

```
import factory

from myapp.models import Experiment


class ExperimentFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Experiment

    # other fields here

    @factory.post_generation
    def tags(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        if not create:
            # Simple build, do nothing.
            return

        if extracted:
            # A list of tags were passed in, use them.
            for tag in extracted:
                self.tags.add(tag)
```

Then you can do:

```
from myapp.factories import ExperimentFactory

ExperimentFactory(name='A Name', tags=['Tag 1', 'Tag 2', 'Another tag',])
```

Note, this won't create tags if you do `ExperimentFactory.build()`, only if you do `ExperimentFactory.create()` or its synonym `ExperimentFactory()`.

Answer (score 2):

finally found the solution:

```py
@factory.post_generation
def post_tags(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
    self.tags.add(u'abc, cde', u'xzy')
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.